# Karma unit test case for calling bootstrap modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, karma-runner

We have an angular 7 application. In that we r using bootstrap modal. So in component we r calling modal using $(#modalId).modal('show'). This jQuery opens bootstrap popup. When we r running Karma test cases using ng test, component creation is getting failed with the below error

```
Typeerror: jQuery.__webpack_imported_module_3_jquery___ default(...)(...).modal is not a function
```

Please help us to solve this issue

Comment: Are we using it correctly?

Comment: I have resolved this error.

1. Import the jquery library in scripts array in build,test in angular.json
2. Added typings.d.ts file with declare var $: any; 
3. In tsconfig.json file add the below one 

 "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
       "../src/typings.d.ts"
    ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this error by following the below steps.

1. Import the jquery library in scripts array in build,test in angular.json
2. Added typings.d.ts file with declare var $: any;
3. In tsconfig.json file add the below one

   "typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types",
   "../src/typings.d.ts"
   ],
4. Now in component.ts, use the below comment $('#modalId').modal('show');